# Bombarded AWS EC2 with K6 - 3000 VU. Connections started timing out and now I can't connect to the instance over SSL or HTTP requests. What is this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-testing, connection-refused, k6

As the title says, did a test 5000 VU max.  As I approached 3000 VU, started getting back connection timed out errors. No HTTP requests went through after that.  It's been locked up ever since.

I've tried rebooting.  Done it several times to no avail.
I've checked the security group.  Still the same settings before this happened allowing tcp on 22 and 80 and https and custom 8080 (my server port) from all ip's.
I've even disabled the EC2 firewall thinking there was something auto blocking the ip used for K6 testing. Since for all intents and purposes it could look like a DDOS attack.

```
sudo su 
ufw disabled
```

Unfortunately this did not work either.

I'm out of ideas for now.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok stopping and instance and starting the same instance is NOT the same as a reboot.  That is what seems to be required.  It now works!